# How to fix Xamarin "Could not find file xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache\4.12.0.4\buildTransitive\monoandroid10.0\..\..\jar\annotations.jar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to build a Xamarin.Forms project and this error came up:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error: Could not find file 'C:\Users\CODED\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache\4.12.0.4\buildTransitive\monoandroid10.0\..\..\jar\annotations.jar'.
File name: 'C:\Users\CODED\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache\4.12.0.4\buildTransitive\monoandroid10.0\..\..\jar\annotations.jar'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

Comment: There is almost no useful information here.  Are we supposed to know what "Wowonder Mobile Native Social Timeline Applications" is?  If this is some sort of sample app, please provide a link.  Are you building for iOS or Android?  What version?  What version of VS, Forms, etc are you using?  Have you tried removing and reinstalling the nuget package causing the error?

Answer (score 3):

Update: This issue is now fixed in `4.12.0.6`

Multiple people have reported the same issue and the problem still exists in the `4.12.0.5` nuget.

The solution is to revert to `4.12.0.2` and wait for the next update.

See: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/545

Comment: Thanks, can confirm with Xamarin.Android.Glide 4.12.02 it builds fine, above, up to ..0.5 produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be caused by different versions.

Try to uninstall the Nuget package and reinstall 4.12.0.2 or 4.12.0.0 to try.